# Missing diagram option SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, relational-theory

I would like to create a relationship between to tables. Normally and in previous versions of sql server and the management studio I would go to database diagrams and draw the relation in the diagram.

[image: my ssms 2016 ctp2]

I have an 2008 sql server and the ssms 2016 ctp2 client. Am I missing something? tested it too by connecting to an other sql server with other credentials etc.

it is there when I use remote desktop to work on the database server... and connect with a windows account. what am i doing wrong?

He lost me at the 48th second: https://youtu.be/PHjwX-cexIA?t=48s

[image]
this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21324448/169714
but what caused the diagram node to disappear when logged in remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a member of db_owner?

See this:

> To use Database Diagram Designer, it must first be set up by a member of the db_owner role to control access to diagrams (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189279%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)